# Maximum value a variable can hold without documentation

Tags: algorithm-analysis, formal-methods

Suppose we work with some particular programming language (like C++) on some particular computer. Furthermore, we want to know which values are minimum and maximum for some particular numeric data type of this language. We can't use any specific tools of our language (like [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)), and have no access to language or system documentation. Specifically, we don't know the lengths of our words. Is there an effective and rather precise way to find out the min/max we want to know?

We can certainly write some loop starting with zero and adding one at each step and wait for an overflow. But it is certainly not an effective way. We can write some loop and check some condition like $\log(\exp(n)) \stackrel{?}{=} n$, but I'm not sure whether this will answer our question.

Comment: I suppose you can only ask about maximum values since the minimum value should always be zero.

Comment: If you're not allowing the use of documentation, the only possible answer is to write a program to figure out the answer. This is, therefore, not just a programming question but a low-level, bit-hacking programming question. Such questions are off-topic on [cs.se] SE.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hm, for once I have to disagree. [Data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) *is* a thing in CS. Techniques like [symbolic execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution) are available -- but, Igor, you *need* assumptions on the initial state resp. parameters.

Comment: That depends on how arithmetic behaves in the language. What happens on an overflow? Wrap-around? Saturated arithmetic? A crash? It is specific to the language, and most languages will provide something like `numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step should be

```
count = 0
while (x*2 > x)
  x = x*2
  count++
```

to find the largest power of 2 that can fit into the variable. Note that doing `+1` instead of `*2` is not only much slower but also fails for floating point numbers (the gaps between large consecutive floating point numbers are bigger than 1). The above procedure should work for both numbers that roll over and numbers that reach infinity.

Once you have a rough estimate, you may perform a binary search in the range from `estimate`, to `2*estimate` to find an exact bound.